# Help with creating an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord

I have a categories model.

```
attr_accessible :name, :parent, :tags, :active, :image
```

Sample data will be something like

```
"Bakery",null,"bakehouse, baker, bakeries, bakers, bakery, bakeshop, biscuit factory, boulangerie,  bread bakery, bread, cake bakery, cake topper, cake toppers, cake, cakes, confectionery, cook shop, pastry kitchen, pastry shop, pastry, patisserie, wedding cake", 1, null
"Beauty & Makeup",null,"makeup, ", 1, null
```

Doing @categories = Category.all gives me all categories with all the fields, now I want to create an array with the tags and the category name. The array data should be like

```
[["Bakery", "bakehouse"]
["Bakery", "baker"]
["Bakery", "bakeries"]
["Bakery", "bakers"]
["Bakery", "bakery"]
.....
["Beauty & Makeup", "makeup"]]
```

how can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@categories.map {|cat| cat.tags.split(/, /).map {|tag| [cat.name, tag]}}` should do the trick.